# Slicing in python issues

Tags: python, slice

I am new to python so please be gentle. I am trying to take the values from the columns begin at 'Ball 1' to 'Ball Set' and create a new set called balls but I keep getting this error

> KeyError: "None of [['Ball_1', 'Ball_Set']] are in the [columns]"

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd

def read_csv(url):
   df = pd.read_csv(url,   sep='\t', na_values=".")
   return df

url ='https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/results/lotto/draw-history/csv'
df = read_csv(url) 

#splices file between the two arguments
Balls = df.loc[:,['Ball_1','Ball_Set']]
print(Balls)
```

I was expecting a print of all the data contained within the columns starting at Ball 1 and then continuing all the way ball set.

Comment: From the looks of it, your columns are called ``Ball 1,...,Ball Set`` **without** underscore. And the values are separated by comma, not by ``\t``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names in the file are named `Ball 1,Ball 2, ...`,  not `Ball_1,Ball_2`. Try removing the underscore.

Also, the separator is `,`, not `\t`. So use `sep=','`.

Complete working code:

```
import pandas as pd

url ='https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/results/lotto/draw-history/csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,   sep=',', na_values=".")

Balls = df.loc[:,['Ball 1','Ball Set']]
print(Balls)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, very helpfull, its only when someone else points out your mistake do you notice simple things like that. thank you again